# WinDbg: .for loop to execute commands X number of times?

Tags: windbg

I want to to `"t"` (trace) and `"dds @esp"` X number of times.

```
.for (r $t0=0; @$t0<10; r $t0=@$t0+1){t;dds @esp;}
```

I tried the above and it doesn't work - it only does the `"dds @esp"` 10 times.

to try to narrow it down, I tried:

```
.for (r $t0=0; @$t0<10; r $t0=@$t0+1){t}
```

but get the followign error:
^ Debuggee already running error in 't'

Can someone assist me with this?  Also are there any guides for learning these scripts from a rookie perspective?

Thanks.

Comment: When I execute this, it works for me. Can you give more details?

Comment: I don't think that there's anything I can add.  I'm actively debugging a C++ debug config console app and was getting tired of doing "t; dds @esp;" manually when I found some info on doing the loop.  when I run this: for (r $t0=0; @$t0<10; r $t0=@$t0+1){t;dds @esp;} I don't see the registers, like when i manually do "t".  Does something else need to be added?

Comment: You can do printf in your loop and print the registers manually. I think that the registers are only printed, when the debugger stops. `.printf "EAX=%08X   EDX=%08X",eax, edx;` etc.

Comment: Have you tried the <count> argument to t?  That would allow you to run multiple instructions (albeit without running intermediary commands).  To me, it seems that 't' takes some time to run, and the script tries to run the next 't' before the first 't' finishes.  You could try using '.sleep <time>' after 't' as a hacky way to see if this is the problem.

Comment: Which version of WinDbg do you use?